# I don't understand Android AutoCompleteTextView Constructor of ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I want to use AutoCompleteTextView in android and read the official developer.android documentation about it.

There is a code snippet which looks like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
     AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
             findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
     textView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }

 private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
     "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
 };
```

I do not understand what the second parameter **(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line)** in the constructor of ArrayAdapter means, where does this come from?

Is it a layout which is available from android or do I have to replace this layout with a layout created on my own and how to define this layout file in that case?

Concrete my code lokks like
xml:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

java:

```
AutoCompleteTextView search =(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.search);
String[] vocabs = new String[1001];
//fill the String array
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line ,vocabs);
search.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: no need to replace it, it is the default layout for each row in your autocompleteview or you may change this if you need a customised layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are calling the constructor of ArrayAdapter with 3 arguments ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)): `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)`

The resource **R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line**  is just one of the default android framework layouts for dropdowns. See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html) a list of other default layouts.

**EDIT to answer your 2nd question**:

You can either use the default android layout (the example you provided should work) or a custom one defined by you. If it's this last case then just create a xml layout for this layout:

**layouts/dropdown_custom_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vocab_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="vocab"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you can use the ArrayAdapter constructor `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)` pointing to your custom layout and to the TextView you want to be populated with vocabs:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.dropdown_custom_view, R.id.vocab_text ,vocabs);
search.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also check that you're populating the `vocabs` array well.

Comment: Thanks! But I would expect to get a dropdown list shown when I enter the first few characters, but nothing happens at all... Do you know what could be the reason for this

Comment: I just tried the demo on a test app and it worked well for me. How did you implement the view in xml? mine is as follows: `<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/countries_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />`

Comment: I added xml and java implementation to the questions

Answer (score 0):

This layout which is available within Android System that's the reason you use `android.R`.It is used to show an item from the array adapter.It is basically a textview with some styling

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom layout for `AutoCompleteTextView` like

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_layout, R.id.text_title, COUNTRIES);
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`custom_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e4e4e4"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        tools:text="AA"
        android:padding="15dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```